# Pass drop down select value from react bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm unable to pass the value from react bootstrap dropdown to function defined. Also, I'm populating the value from category props. Below is my code:

```
handleDropdownChange = (evtKey) => {
  console.log(evtKey)
}

<DropdownButton
  onSelect={(event) => this.handleDropdownChange(event)}
  title=""
  id="category-dropdown"
>
  {category.map((category, i) =>
    <MenuItem key={i}>{category.path}</MenuItem>)}
</DropdownButton>
```

Comment: i bet that you forget to specify `key` variable inside `this.handleDropdownChange(category[key])` or event category.As you can see you pass `event` variable to the arrow function but you use `key` instead

Answer (score 0):

The MenuItem's **key** should be **eventKey**.

```
<DropdownButton onSelect={this.handleDropdownChange} 
                          title=""
                          id="category-dropdown">
              {category.map((category, i) =>
                  <MenuItem eventKey={i}>{category.path}</MenuItem>)
              }
</DropdownButton>
```